# Get element id from class name in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I found similar questions, but difference in my case is, I have same `class name` in multiple radio-buttons, and I want to figure out which radio button is clicked?
HTML code is like -

```
<input type='radio' value='1' id='country_1' name='countries' class='option_selector'>
<label for='country_1'>India</label>
<input type='radio' value='2' id='country_2' name='countries' class='option_selector'>
<label for='country_2'>USA</label>
<input type='radio' value='3' id='country_3' name='countries' class='option_selector'>
<label for='country_3'>UK</label>

<input type='radio' value='1' id='city_1' name='cities' class='option_selector'>
<label for='city_1'>Jaipur</label>
<input type='radio' value='2' id='city_2' name='cities' class='option_selector'>
<label for='city_2'>Delhi</label>
<input type='radio' value='3' id='city_3' name='cities' class='option_selector'>
<label for='city_3'>Mumbai</label>
```

My jQuery is like -

```
$('.option_selector').click(function () {
    var id = $('.option_selector').attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

But it always returns the `id` of 1st element having the class name `option_selector`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `this` to refer clicked element

```
$('.option_selector').click(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  // or var id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks. will select as answer in 10 minutes (SO timelimit). Upvoted :)

Answer (score 4):

You're re-selecting *all* matching elements here:

```
$('.option_selector').attr('id');
```

But since the `click` handler runs in the context of the element which was clicked, you can just use the `this` keyword to refer to that element:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

or possibly, even more simply:

```
this.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, the key is to use the keyword, `this` to keep the context within the *current radio* button. Thus `var id = $('.option_selector').attr('id');` should be:

```
var id = this.id;
```

However, the one event that is appropriate to use with **radio buttons** (and checkboxes) is the `change` event. You only want to fire the code when there's been a `change`:

```
$('.option_selector').change(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
});
```

Or:

```
$('.option_selector').on('change', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: For some reasons I need radio buttons to behave like checkboxes (i.e. ability to **un-select**). **Would `change` event be helpful in doing that?** still figuring out a way. (Since the original question was already answered and answer was selected too, I am just upvoting your answer). Thanks

Comment: No, changing the event would not change the behavior. If I may ask, why would you like radio buttons to behave like checkboxes? Why not use checkboxes?

Comment: It's for a simple quiz program for medical students, which is replica of our actual Board Exam. They people give 4 options with radio buttons (with ability to un-check) not checkboxes. So I don't want to create unnecessary confusion to the students for the actual Exam.

Comment: Would you like to create a new question for this?

Comment: I am just testing with **if(checked) then uncheck** `on click` event. if that fails, unfortunately I will have to create a new question

Comment: Unfortunately I had to ask it as another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155382/toogle-radio-buttons-checked-status-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are monitoring the click events for but a simple way to get the options that are selected is:

```
$('.option_selector:checked');
```

This will give you a list of only the checked checkboxes. Then you can go through and get the ids or whatever you would like.

```
$('.option_selector:checked').each(function() {
var $currentcheckbox = $(this);
});
```

This is an alternative to monitoring all of the click events.