# Toggle Radio buttons checked status in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to slightly extend functions of Radio buttons, i.e. ability to un-check (on click, if it was previously checked).

**HTML** code is like -

```
<input type='radio' value='1' id='country_1' name='countries' class='option_selector'>
<label for='country_1'>India</label>
<input type='radio' value='2' id='country_2' name='countries' class='option_selector'>
<label for='country_2'>USA</label>
<input type='radio' value='3' id='country_3' name='countries' class='option_selector'>
<label for='country_3'>UK</label>

<input type='radio' value='1' id='city_1' name='cities' class='option_selector'>
<label for='city_1'>Jaipur</label>
<input type='radio' value='2' id='city_2' name='cities' class='option_selector'>
<label for='city_2'>Delhi</label>
<input type='radio' value='3' id='city_3' name='cities' class='option_selector'>
<label for='city_3'>Mumbai</label>
```

**jQuery** so far is -

```
$('.option_selector').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($('#' + id).is(':checked')) {
        $("#" + id).prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $("#" + id).prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

I know why this is Not working - because eveytime I click on radio-button its initial status will be checked, therefore final status will be unchecked.
But, I couldn't figure out to make it work in the desired way.

**p.s.** - For those, who are wondering, why I am not using checkboxes instead of radio buttons : I am trying to make quiz **replica** (for practice purpose) of My actual Examining body. They people don't use checkboxes, instead use radio buttons with an additional feature of un-select the option. So, I am just trying to avoid any un-necessary confusion.

Edit - 1 : It may or may not be duplicate of mentioned question. But, the solution in the mentioned question works on the basis of "group of radios deselectable by their name", which is not solving my problem.

Comment: It's just so easy -> **http://jsfiddle.net/p26b489b/**

Comment: @adeneo That doesn't quite seem to work: http://i.imgur.com/lsJSaft.png. Anyway, this question and its variations have been asked so many times before it's undoubtedly a duplicate. If only someone with a JavaScript gold badge was here to clean that up :)

Comment: @DrewGaynor, I am looking at the solutions provided here and in the linked questions. Sorry, if it's duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would combine the `click` event and use a `data-attribute` to keep track of the state of the radio buttons:

```
$('.option_selector').on('click', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    if( $(this).data('checked') ) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        $(this).data('checked', false);
    } else {
        $(this).data('checked', true);
    }
    console.log( id );
    $(':radio[name=' + this.name + ']').not(this).data('checked', false);
});
```

```js
//another way to re-write the code
$('.option_selector').on('click', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var waschecked = $(this).data('checked');
    if( waschecked ) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
    $(this).data('checked', !waschecked)
    console.log( id );
    $(':radio[name=' + this.name + ']').not(this).data('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' value='1' id='country_1' name='countries' class='option_selector'>
<label for='country_1'>India</label>
<input type='radio' value='2' id='country_2' name='countries' class='option_selector'>
<label for='country_2'>USA</label>
<input type='radio' value='3' id='country_3' name='countries' class='option_selector'>
<label for='country_3'>UK</label>
<br/>
<input type='radio' value='1' id='city_1' name='cities' class='option_selector'>
<label for='city_1'>Jaipur</label>
<input type='radio' value='2' id='city_2' name='cities' class='option_selector'>
<label for='city_2'>Delhi</label>
<input type='radio' value='3' id='city_3' name='cities' class='option_selector'>
<label for='city_3'>Mumbai</label>
```

Comment: sorry I didn't get you completely, how/where to put it?

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari, please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Before your answer, I tried many answers. But yours is the one, which worked in my case, also I was able to understand what's happening here (otherwise previously some answers worked too, but I was not able to figure out, why they are working). Thanks for you time. :)

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think, the only thing you need to do is check if checked. Don't include the else statement.

```
if($(this).is(':checked')) $(this).prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: this is what you what then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6191732/5273689

Comment: Yes, similar to this, but the answer worked for me was by @manji on the same question. Don't know why the marked answer didn't work for me (may be because of name properties settings). Anyways thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the `attr` like this:

```
$('.option_selector').click(function () {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
if($('#' + id).attr('checked')) {
    $("#" + id).attr("checked", false);
} else {
    $("#" + id).attr("checked", true);
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/mqpqgfL3/

Comment: Is it because it works only for jQuery<1.6?

Comment: Please let me know what's wrong with this code

Comment: @SandeepNayak This could have something to do with it: http://i.imgur.com/AqCxa4u.png. I advise thoroughly testing your answers before submitting.

Comment: It's more because `attr` is the wrong method for a radio button, the reason this works at all is because the attribute isn't set, the property is.

Comment: @DrewGaynor: Got it.Thanks :)